# Pfsense IPsec VPN not listening on port 500?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, pfsense, l2tp

I am trying to setup a home VPN with IPsec as I have read about PPTP having some security problems and being outdated. I found an article on the web that shows you how to setup an IPsec VPN [here](http://dekapitein.vorkbaard.nl/tech-1/how-to-set-up-ipsec-tunneling-in-pfsense-2-0-release-for-road-warriors) which I was able to follow and setup, but when I went to connect to it I could not. I tried port scanning the router from the LAN and by using a computer outside of my LAN and both scans concluded that port 500 (the VPN port) was closed. Is there something else I have to do to set it up to listen so clients can connect? I checked the error logs and everything was clean so I am confused here.

In addition, from what I know IPsec is supposed to be a wrapper around L2TP so am I supposed to setup L2TP first and then configure my IPsec to work with L2TP which would explain why it's not "listening"? If so, could you kindly share a link with me that helps me accomplish that? I've gone though the first couple pages of Google and all I can seem to dig up is PPTP guides. Many thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?  I am in a similar situation.

Comment: @jmreicha Unfortunately I have not. I ended up using OpenVPN instead but if I find a solution (I will probably keep trying), I will post it here.

Comment: If it is of any help to you, I had some (limited) success setting up L2TP.  I opened port 500, 1701 on the firewall and was able to connect using the android VPN client.  However, I wasn't able to do anything outside my local network and I am not able to get it working with any other clients.

Comment: @jmreicha Yes, I believe L2TP and PPTP on Pfsense work fine, but for some reason IPsec does not. Are you running IPsec without L2TP, or are you running both IPsec and L2TP?

Comment: I couldn't get anything to work with both.  The piece I got working was with L2TP only.

Answer (score 2):

IKE traffic to establish a phase 1 tunnel runs over port 500 of the UDP protocol; a typical port scan only checks TCP ports.  This is because it's much harder to simply 'check' a UDP port for openness without knowing what protocol is operating on the port - many services won't respond to a UDP packet that's malformed, and many systems won't send ICMP unreachable responses to indicate a non-listening UDP port.  See `-sU` scan section [here](http://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html) for more information.

Check the logs in the pfsense device, and turn up logging verbosity if necessary, to get some information on what's going on with the connection attempts.